# IdentityServer4 xamarin authentication

Tags: c#, xamarin, identityserver4

I am building test xamarin app(cross platform ios and android) and would like to create a sample for authentication with identity server 4. I have knowledge for mvc, angular clients, but I never did it with xamarin mobile client. What grant type to use and is there any helpful resource I could look at to get a guide to where to start?

Comment: https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples/tree/master/iOSClient

Comment: This link will help a lot on architecture and other implementation issue using Xamarin form
https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/master/docs/Enterprise-Application-Patterns-using-XamarinForms.pdf
Also the code samples of the book on GitHub;
https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers